# How does a for-loop with four 'things' in the parenthesis work i Javascript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I came across some code here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2922778/2176900 that started off like this:

```
for (i = 0, j = nvert-1; i < nvert; j = i++) {...`
```

and I don't understand what it does when it has four things within the parenthesis ("i = 0", "j = nvert-1", "i < nvert" and "j = i++"). I've obviously been trying to google this, but can't seem to find any answers. I'm sure if I just knew what the things in the parenthesis was called I'd be glad.

Thanks

Comment: You forgot to declare the variables with `var`.

Comment: Your Javascript book doesn't cover this in great detail?

Comment: @elclanrs - the [original code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2922778/2176900) this loop is taken from has the `var`.

Comment: There's always [ECMA-262: The for Statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.3). :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't have four things; it still has three.

- **The pre-loop statement**
  `i = 0, j = nvert-1`
- **The iteration condition**
  `i < nvert`
- **The post-iteration action**
  `j = i++`

That pre-loop statement is actually probably supposed to read:
`var i = 0, j = nvert-1`

Remember that we can declare multiple variables in a single declaration. That's what's happening here.

Comment: So the "j = i++" means that i increases with 1 after every iteration and that j takes on whatever value that gives i?

Comment: @Henrik: Almost - `i++` evaluates to the value _before_ the increment, so `j` takes on the old value. This is fairly basic Javascript stuff so you should consider reading your book through again.

Comment: Gotcha. I'm just more used to seeing "j = i" just before the closing curly bracket in a for-loop. Thanks though!

Answer (score 4):

To add to the excellent answers from @LightnessRacesinOrbit and @basilikum, here is a tip I find helpful when looking at an unusual `for` loop like this: break it down to a more primitive form.

Any `for` loop:

```
for( initialize; condition; advance ) {
    // loop body here
}
```

can be translated to an equivalent `while` loop:

```
initialize;
while( condition ) {
    // loop body here
    advance;
}
```

So the loop you found:

```
for ( i = 0, j = nvert-1;  i < nvert;  j = i++ ) {
    // loop body here
}
```

could be written:

```
i = 0,  j = nvert - 1;
while( i < nvert ) {
    // loop body here
    j = i++;
}
```

Now we can take that and break it down to even simpler steps.

As @basilikum noted, the first line:

```
i = 0,  j = nvert - 1;
```

is the same as:

```
i = 0;
j = nvert - 1;
```

and the last line of the loop:

```
    j = i++;
```

is the same as:

```
    j = i;
    i = i + 1;
```

So putting those back into the code we end up with:

```
i = 0;
j = nvert - 1;
while( i < nvert ) {
    // loop body here
    j = i;
    i = i + 1;
}
```

That's more verbose than the original `for` loop, but it may be easier to think about if the original loop is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the syntax, that the user Lightness Races in Orbit already explained, the reason to have such a loop is most probably to loop over an array and always access two adjacent items.

```
var list = [1,2,3,4],
    nvert = list.length;

for (i = 0, j = nvert-1; i < nvert; j = i++) {
    //...
}
```

First iteration:

```
i = 0; //index of first item
j = nvert-1; //indext of last item
```

The following iterations:

```
j = i;     //j becomes the old value of i
i = i + 1; //i gets incremented by one
```

So if you consider the array `[1,2,3,4]` then `i` and `j` would represent the following items for each iteration:

```
//first iteration
i => 1
j => 4

//second iteration
i => 2
j => 1

//third iteration
i => 3
j => 2

//fourth iteration
i => 4
j => 3
```